# 1084: error: rightbrace before end of program needed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm getting a syntax error but I don't know what is causing the error. I checked all the code, and even re-wrote as new, but I still can't avoid the error.

This is my code :

Code for **Avoider.as**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

    public class AvoiderGame extends MovieClip
    {
        public var enemy:Enemy;
        public var avatar:Avvatar;
        public var gameTimer:Timer;

        public function AvoiderGame()
        {
                enemy = new Enemy();
                addChild( enemy );

                avatar = new Avatar();
                addChild( avatar );
                avatar.x = mouseX;
                avatar.Y = mouseY;

                gameTimer = new Timer( 25 );
                gameTimer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, moveEnemyAndAvatar );
                gameTimer.start();
        }

        public function onTick(timerEvent:TimerEvent):void 
        {
                enemy.moveDownABit();
                avatar.x = mouseX;
                avatar.y = mouseY;

                if ( avatar.hitTestObject(enemy) ) { gameTimer.stop(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for **Enemy.as**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Enemy extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Enemy( startX:Number, startY:Number )
        { x = startX; y = startY;}

        public function moveDownABit():void
        { y = y + 3; }
    }
}
```

Code for **Avator.as**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class Avatar extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Avatar()
        { /* is an empty function */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this all the code in your program?

Comment: hello, yes its the full code

Comment: Got a line number that causes the error? or at least paste the full error message. Can you be sure functions like `moveEnemyAndAvatar` and `moveDownABit` are not involved in causing the error message?

Comment: This is obviously not the full code.  I just copied it into a project.  First error:  Enemy and Avvatar not defined.  Second error:  Access of possible undefined property Y (avatar.Y instead of avatar.y).  Third error:  Access of possible undefined property moveEnemyAndAvatar.  No problems with bracing.  Voting to close as there's nothing in this that would cause a 1084 error.

Comment: ( Enemy.as https://pastebin.com/Jv7x3Za7 ) ( AvoiderGame.as https://pastebin.com/N6ibMB7r ) ( Avatar.as https://pastebin.com/4NZEXPxj )  - Sorry for trouble - anyone edited my code now i get 3 errors on avoidergame.as 10,15,24

Comment: @ManuelCortellini use the `@` symbol to notify specific user. No one gets notified of future replies except you.

Comment: In _Enemy.as_ why does it say `x = ` when no variable `var x` was declared? Maybe you want something like `this.x = startX;`? ... In _Avator.as_ is it really okay to use an **empty** constructor function?